# Run time error 424: object require - Extract data using API link

Tags: regex, vba, web-scraping

I am working on the VBA code to extract the data from website using API link.

I am trying to use regex to scoop out the portion for exchange rate for `usd_sgd` & `jpy_sgd_100` into same worksheet in cell B2 & C2.

I try to use `if else then` statement for 2 different pattern `"usd_sgd"` and `"jpy_sgd_100"`.

When I run the code it yields a run-time error:

> "Run time error 424 object required"

on line:

```
For Each match In matches
```

I want to extract exchange rate data for "usd_sgd" and "jpy_sgd_100", from the stated API link, into same worksheet, in cell B2 & C2. How do I resolve the current error and achieve this result please?

Code:

```
Public Sub ExchangeRate()
    Dim results(), matches As Object, s As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=5aa64bc2-d234-43f3-892e-2f587a220f74&fields=end_of_week,usd_sgd,jpy_sgd_100&limit=1&sort=end_of_week%20desc", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False

        If .Pattern = "usd_sgd"":""(.*?)""" Then
           .MultiLine = True
           Set matches = .Execute(s)
           ReDim results(1 To matches.Count)

         ElseIf .Pattern = "jpy_sgd_100"":""(.*?)""" Then
            .MultiLine = True
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            ReDim results(1 To matches.Count)
         End If

   End With
   Dim match As Variant, r As Long
   For Each match In matches
       r = r + 1
       results(r) = match.submatches(0)
   Next
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
       .Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
       .Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `.Pattern` so you never `.Execute(s)` and therefore never set `matches` to anything other than `Nothing`. Set `.pattern` to required pattern.

A re-write might look like:

```
Public Sub ExchangeRate()
    Dim results(), s As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=5aa64bc2-d234-43f3-892e-2f587a220f74&fields=end_of_week,usd_sgd,jpy_sgd_100&limit=1&sort=end_of_week%20desc", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With

    Dim pattern As Variant, patterns(), i As Long

    patterns = Array("""usd_sgd"":""(.*?)""", """jpy_sgd_100"":""(.*?)""")

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(patterns) + 1)

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True

        For i = LBound(patterns) To UBound(patterns)

            .pattern = patterns(i)

            Set matches = .Execute(s)

            If matches.Count > 0 Then results(i + 1) = matches(0).Submatches(0)
        Next

    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(2, 2).Resize(UBound(results), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
    End With

End Sub
```